# Parse Local Json data in background or isolates in flutter and highlight search text

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

1. Working on a project using local json data, but the app takes too long to open due to the size of the json file 10mb , how can i use isolates or parse in background to speed up the reading and loading of json file.

I tried using https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/background-parsing for the local json data, but it did not work because it is for a network fetch.

i am using this to read the json data

```
Future<void> readJsonFile() async {
final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/products.json');
final productData = await json.decode(response);

var list = productData["items"] as List<dynamic>;

setState(() {
allProducts = [];
allProducts = list.map((e) => Product.fromJson(e)).toList();
filteredProducts = allProducts;
});
}
```

Can this be done in and isolate or parsed in the backround.

2. I also want a search item to be highlihgted. such as in the image